# Can non-FAA towers employ foreigners?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control

I understand you must be a US citizen in order to work ATC with FAA.

Is it different with the non-FAA towers? Could I as a European citizen be employed (working visa/greencard) there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[14 CFR 65.31](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/65.31) and 65.33 do not mention citizenship as a requirement.

[This job listing with Serco](https://careers-sercona.icims.com/jobs/48960/air-traffic-ctrl-spec-terminal%2c-troutdale%2c-or-%28ttd%29/job) for a position at TTD says that you must:

> - Be eligible to work for Serco under the Federal Immigration Laws
> - Be able to receive an interim security suitability clearance granted by FAA Security derived from a public trust background check.

According to [ClearanceJobs.com](https://news.clearancejobs.com/2021/02/22/can-a-green-card-holder-get-a-public-trust-position/), US citizenship is not a requirement to be eligible for a Public Trust position.

So it seems like it would be possible for you to work at a contract tower. But this is the sort of question that you really should ask of the hiring manager at a specific company where you would like to work.